# Read an indefinite number of digits from a file, store in an array (no space)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want to read a file that contains this (example):

```
194920392038122341
```

and store each digit in an integer array. For instance, a[0] would be 1, a[1] would be 9, etc.

I tried using something like this to read the digits and store them in an array:

```
    int n = 0;
    vector<int> numbers; 

    ifstream in
    in.open("input.txt");

    while (in >> n)
    {
        numbers.push_back(n);
    }

    int* array = &numbers[0];
```

However, for some reason, this doesn't read the individual digits from the file. It reads them as "12", "34", "35" etc.

Comment: Use [`std::istream::get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) instead of `in >> n`.

Comment: `in >> n` reads in white-space separated integers.

Comment: but then I would have to convert the vector of chars to an array of ints, right?

Comment: @Mil3d Reminder: `'1' - '0'` yields `1.`

Comment: thank you, that helps. but now some numbers are being read as "-32". why would that be?

Comment: this is what I did:
      while (in_stream.get(next))
        {
            unsorted.push_back((next - '0'));
        }

        int* array = &unsorted[0];

Comment: @Mil3d _"why would that be?"_ Because you did a mistake in your code probably.

Comment: No one has answered yet, so feel free to update the question with your revision. Whoops. Too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
char n = 0;
vector<int> numbers; 

ifstream in("input.txt");

while (in.get(n)) {
   if(std::isdigit(n) {
       numbers.push_back(n - '0');
   }
}

int* array = &numbers[0];
```

Comment: It works! Just to improve my understanding, why is the isdigit step necessary given that all the characters in the file *are* digit? I know it doesn't work without that, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Mil3d It's not necessary if you're absolutely sure, but there might occur characters like `'\n'` in your input stream.